# Looking for counterexamples (non-domains)

Tags: abstract-algebra, examples-counterexamples, rngs

I stumbled upon this question [Why doesn't $xa = x$ for all $x \in R$ imply that $a$ is the unit of $R$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1121301/why-doesnt-xa-x-for-all-x-in-r-imply-that-a-is-the-unit-of-r) and understood the given answers. But it got me thinking about a counterexample, and I was hoping to find something along these lines:

We have for $a\in R$ and for all $x\in R$

$$xa=x$$
so
$$x(a-1)=0$$

**$R$ has no zero divisors (for instance, $R$ is a domain - careful, this assumes $1\neq 0$ and commutativity):** then the above implies that $x=0$ or $a=1$. But see the link above to understand why $a=1$ does not work here.

**$R$ HAS zero divisors:** Here I was hoping to find an example where $a-1\neq 0$ is a zero divisor, hence showing that $a$ need not be a unit. I tried thinking about $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$ and $2 \times 2$ matrices, but then the condition $xa=x$ does not hold for all $x$.

Should there be further thinking about if $1\neq 0$?

We can also say that $R=\{0\}$, taking $R$ without $1$. Then this is a counterexample since $a=0$.

Comment: @rschwieb Thank you! So by $a-1\neq 0$ being a zero divisor, we know that $1)$ $a$ is not the identity (but could be a different unit), and $2)$ $a-1$ is not a unit, since an element cannot be a unit and zero divisor at the same time.

Comment: OK, i see your intention now.

Comment: I’m still unclear on what you’re asking. The answer you linked to demonstrates that if $a$ has the property you seek, and $1$ exists, then $a=1$.  When you ask “is there an example of such an $a$ with $a-1$ a nonzero zero divisor, this presupposes an identity exists, and hence by the discussion, $a=1$, and $a-1=0$. So the answer to that is “there are no such examples”

Answer (score 1):

*After a week of inactivity on the question it also looks like you are not going to make any adjustments, so I answer it here as-is. It seems like there is no way to rescue the posed question anyhow.*

---

It seems like you may not have understood the linked question's solutions.

[One of the solutions](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1347200/29335) to the question you linked to demonstrates, independently of the ring being a domain or not begin a domain, that if $R$ has an identity $1$, then there is no other element $a$ acting like the identity on the right.

To say it again, more explicitly:

> If $R$ has an identity $1$ and there is an $a\in R$ such that $x(a-1)=0$ for all $r\in R$, then $a=1$ (i.e. $a-1=0$.)

In light of the fact that $x$ can be $1$, this is obvious, right?

If you are searching for a counterexample in the form of a nonzero rng that has an element $a$ satisfying $xa=x$ for all $x\in R$, and $R$ doesn't have an identity (and hence no invertible elements at all), then that was *also* already provided by the solution.

---

> We can also say that $R=\{0\}$, taking $R$ without $1$. Then this is a counterexample since $a=0$.

And $\{0\}$ is a ring with identity, contrary to your statement.
How do you figure it would be a counterexample? A counterexample would require finding a nonzero element with your property, and this ring has no nonzero elements.